# Removing horizontal/vertical lines from image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I want remove vertical and horizontal lines from the image.
Then here is my method

```
def removeLines(self):
    # Convert to THRESH_BINARY
    self.retval, self.im = cv2.threshold(self.im, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    chop = 6  #  If line length is more than chop . It will set to white
    threshold = 200 #  pixel's color
    lineColor = 150  #  if is line. set color 255:white   0:black
    (height, width) = self.im.shape
    #  loop each pixel
    for i in xrange(height):
        for j in xrange(width):
            #  if is black point
            if self.im[i][j] < threshold:
                countWidth = 0
                #  remove vertical line    if <threshold then  count+1
                for c in range(j, width):
                    if self.im[i][c] < threshold:
                        countWidth += 1
                    else:
                        break
                #  if length is more than chop.  then remove line
                if countWidth >= chop:
                    for c in range(countWidth):
                        try:
                            #  check this pixel's around pixel
                            if self.im[i+1, j+c] > threshold and self.im[i-1, j+c] > threshold:
                                self.im[i, j+c] = lineColor
                        except IndexError:
                            pass

                j += countWidth
```

Removing horizontal is same to remove vertical line

Here is my result.
I convert image to black and white first(yellow background and purple digits)
Then draw all line to gray(cyan in matplotlib)

[image]
[image]
[image]

If two line are overlapping, this method cannot detect.
And if a line is in a digit, it will mistakenly deleted this line.
How do I improve this algorithm

Comment: Please add original images to your question.

Comment: If two line are overlapping, this method cannot detect. -> I think this is because of your chop value being set to 6. Have u tried morphological operations to filter the horizontal and vertical lines